# Select all elements between two elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I have this HTML, how can I select all elements between the two h2 elements with CSS? I can't use jQuery.

```
<h2 ></h2>
<p></p>
<table></table>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<h2 ></h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Comment: No, CSS really only "scans" in one direction.  The closest you would get are the [General Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator). That however will select all siblings, unless you exclude some with [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you use some `<div>` to wrap your content, then selecting this div and `:not(h2)` should work:

```css
.wrapper > :not(h2)
```

By using `>`, you select only *direct* children.

```css
.wrapper> :not(h2) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h2>heading1</h2>
  <p>paragraph1</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>el of table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>paragraph1</p>
  <p>paragraph1</p>
  <h2>heading2</h2>
</div>
```

Run the snippet to see the result or visit this pen: https://codepen.io/matysflance/pen/aeGrKe

Comment: I've cleaned your answer up a bit, hope you don't mind!

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the OP's question.  In the original question, the second <h2> isn't last, so just selecting :not(h2) doesn't select only the items between the two <h2> tags.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a combination of the [`:not()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and the [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).

You can apply styling to the first `h2` siblings and override styling for the second one, then you will apply styling to the in "between" elements with CSS, something like:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h2 ~ *:not(h2) {
  color: red;
}

h2 ~ h2 ~ * {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<h2>Title</h2>

<p>Paragraph</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>

<h2>Title</h2>

<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```

Run the snippet to see the result or visit the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6yc1knod/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This can't help as the code contains other elements which i don't want to select

Comment: @IbrahimSaber Have you tried the updated answer? That seems to work just fine...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the element types vary, you can't select all elements between two elements, like in your example. But you can exclude the first and last elements, which effectively does the same thing.

```css
article > * {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

article > :first-child,
article > :last-child {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h2>heading</h2>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <h2>heading</h2>
</article>
```